# Why cannot I use long primitive as expression of the switch() part?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have noticed that I cannot use `long`  as expression of the switch() part.

I don't understand why.

This primitive worse than others?

What's wrong with `long`?

Comment: You can of course use `char` type. Did you try it?

Comment: Corrected mistake. thanks

Comment: You can only use byte, char, short or int (from doc). Do you really need more than 2 billion cases in your switch?

Comment: Yes) duplicate but I don't found it

Comment: Should I delete topic?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Map as a sort of switch

Eg instead of:

```
long choice = getChoice();
if (choice == 1L) {
   System.out.println("Do action one");
} else if (choice == 2L) {
   System.out.println("Do action two");
} else {
   System.out.println("Default action");
}
```

you can do

```
Map<Long, Runnable> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
actionMap.put(1L, () -> System.out.println("Do action one"));
actionMap.put(2L, () -> System.out.println("Do action two"));
Runnable defaultAction = () -> System.out.println("Default action");
...
Long choice = getChoice();
Runnable action = actionMap.getOrDefault(choice, defaultAction);
action.run();
```

The map approach will execute in [constant time O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) whereas the if/then/else will execute in [linear time O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)

Comment: That is not a `switch` statement.

Comment: I don't understand your thought

Comment: I know it's not a `switch`. But it's sometimes much better than an if/then/else as it performs in [constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time).

Comment: @LanceJava an `if..then..else` binary tree is O(log(n)). (P.S. `new Map<Long, Runnable>()` will give you a "cannot instantantiate an interface" compiler error)

Comment: If you had 1000 cases in your if then else it would perform in O(1000). With a Map it would perform in O(1)

Comment: why Runnable ? hmm....

Comment: Can you write switch example and map and comparison?

Comment: @gstackoverflow because a `Runnable` is the interface for things that can be `run`.

Answer (score 1):

It's how switch was built into Java.  What you can do, though, is cast long values as int types before you put them into switch.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A `switch` works with the `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int` primitive data types.

The reason you can't switch on a `long` is that there is no need. In order to meaningfully switch on a `long`, you would need to add a `case` statement for every single value you want to switch to. (The only reason `int`s are supported is because that is the default integral type; even for `int`s its rather a waste.)

Comment: and why does long doesn't сontains at this list?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I think that's not a valid question.

Comment: only long excluded from all primitive list.it is strange

Comment: And, as of Java 7, strings.

Comment: @aliteralmind By popular demand, of course.

Comment: that is a bad answer, long can be used as required type for enumeration (that is not java enum). There is ZERO reason why can't you switch over long except someone had brilliant idea to limit it for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, you can't use long (or String etc) in a case statement. If you really want to use a long, the obvious choice is to use if/then/else.

eg:

```
if (someValue == 1L) { 
    println("one"); 
} else if (someValue == 2L) { 
    println("two"); 
} ...
} else if (someValue == 1000L) { 
    println("thousand"); 
}
```

But if you have many options, this will perform very badly since you need to evaluate each condition. What I was suggesting in my other answer is to use a Map instead

```
Map<Long, Runnable> map = new HashMap<Long, Runnable>();
map.put(1L, new Runnable() {
    public void run() { println("one"); }
});
map.put(2L, new Runnable() { ... });
...
map.put(1000L, new Runnable() { ... });
```

And then you can use

```
map.get(someValue).run();
```

The map version will perform in constant time O(1) whereas the if/then/else will perform in linear time O(N). As you can see, this construct can be used with Long, String or any object you like.

Comment: Since Long is not allowed in the Java language for a switch statement, tell us what you are trying to do and perhaps we can offer an alternative.

Comment: I'm creating a switch construct based on long which performs in constant time FFS!!!

Comment: You will need to transform your "Long" value into an integer ... is there a reasonable mapping to do so?  If you have a set of descrete Long values that are used, then one alternative is to create a HashMap <Long,int> map, and use the "int" in the switch statement.

Comment: I give up... I can't be arsed trying to explain myself any more

Answer (score -2):

When you use a programming language, you are restricted to that language's definition.  In this case, the Java `switch` statement

> works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types

according to the Java language [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Sure would like to understand the downvote for a accurate answer!

Comment: because your answer is not helpful. your answer is not response to my question.

Comment: I can understand your frustration .. but you are closer to what you are trying to do than we are.  Can you give a snippet of your code so we can try to help?

Comment: I have not code. it is question from certification

Comment: If that is a question from a certification test, then the simple answer is that the Java language specification does not allow a long type in the switch statement.  There is nothing wrong with Java. There is nothing inherently wrong with a long.  The language only allows int and certain other primitive types that can be converted into an int to be used in a switch statement. A long cannot be converted to an int without losing information.